# Why The results of nmap "- ST" and "- SS" are different

Tags: nmap

when i use
sudo nmap -sS "IP"
Only a 10 ports are open
But when I use
sudo nmap -sT "IP"
All ports are open.

I don't know why. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

nmap `-sS` is a sealth scan while nmap with `-sT` is a TCP connect scan.
Sealth scan means that nmap send a **SYN** to the target machine and then that target machine reply to the system with **ACK** and **SYN** than again the host machine send a message which terminates the connection, during this process nmap scan for the open ports. Now what happens with TCP connect scan is that it does the complete 3-way handshaking with the target machine, due to which it is slower than sealth scan and also very noisy due to which the target machine can detect that it is being scanned.